How to show a virtual entity into the sidebar menu?
I have an admin class that uses a virtual entity. It shows in the dashboard but it doesnt show in the sidebar menu.
services.yaml:
    services:
         admin.test.virtual:
         class: App\Admin\Test\ReaLAdmin
         tags:
             - { name: sonata.admin, group: 'Virtual', model_class: App\Entity\Virtual\VirtualEntity, manager_type: orm, label: 'Virtual', controller: App\Controller\Admin\VirtualController }

How can I display that also in the sidebar menu? I havent found the right doc/s for my issue.
